# aws-sdk/client-firehose record.data limit size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

we wanted to use [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-firehose) for firehose logging.
First we implemented this [putRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html) but we got validation error like:
`ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'record.data' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 1024000`

Then we used [putRecordBatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecordBatch.html) because the acceptable data limit is higher.

You can check the limits [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/limits.html).

But the problem was still not solved. I still keep getting the same validation error.
What could be the problem or how can I increase the data limit.